# how to use gradle for dependence in android project

Tags: android, gradle

project A:Actionbarsherlock
project B:SlidingMenu
project C:myAPP

A is a library project of B and C;
B is a library project of C;

so how to write the build.gradle and settings.gradle.

below is mine files:
A Actionbarsherlock:build gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'



android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'support-v4', version: 'r7'
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest {
            srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        res {
            srcDir 'res'
        }
        assets {
            srcDir 'assets'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        aidl {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is build.gradle for B SlidingMenu:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
}
}

 apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
dependencies {
    compile project(":actionbarsherlock")
    compile group: 'com.google.android', name: 'support-v4', version: 'r7'
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest {
            srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        res {
            srcDir 'res'
        }
        assets {
            srcDir 'assets'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        aidl {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
}
```

here is C myAPP build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "17"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 17
}
dependencies {
    compile project(":actionbarsherlock")
    compile project(":SlidingMenu")
}
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest {
            srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
        java {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        res {
            srcDir 'res'
        }
        assets {
            srcDir 'assets'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
        aidl {
            srcDir 'src'
        }
    }
}
```

}

here is Project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
}
}
```

and the settings.gradle

```
include 'actionbarsherlock'
include 'SlidingMenu'
include 'YueClient'
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably unrelated,

You can now use com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+ to get compatible action bar instead of Sherlock.

Check full doc here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html